# How do I run a third-party API through Azure AD?

Tags: .net, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I am looking for a way to run a third-party's OAuth2 (Authorization Code flow) API through Azure AD, because I really like the MSAL library in .NET and wouldn't want to reinvent the wheel, so to speak.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) supports all OAuth 2.0 flows.

Steps to use OAuth 1. Go to Azure Active Directory, the click on App registrations and then click New Registration. enter image description here

1. Enter Name and select accounts in this organizational directory only and click ok

[image]

[image]

2. Then click on App registration and click new create applications
3. Click Application ID URi and set this

[image]

4. Copy this Application Id
5. Create role

[image]

[image]

6. Create client and add permission then click on grant admin consent for default directory and then click on yes

[image]

7. After above steps
8. Click certificates & secrets and then click on new client secret and then enter description and expires month and click add

[image]

[image]

[image]

9. Copy new client secret values and copy client id.

[image]

10. Get Endpoints

[image]

11. Passing this values and get token

[image]

12. Pass token to Authorization.

[image]

13. Check token open jwt.ms

[image]

[image]

Fundamental [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/auth-oauth2)

[16](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/auth-oauth2): [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/auth-oauth2)

Fundamental [OAuth 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/auth-oauth2) Authentication with Azure Active Directory by Microsoft Documents